# Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema. - options has an unknown property 'publicPath'

Tags: javascript, python, django, vue.js

I've been trying to merge Vue and Django for a long time, but my efforts are even. Here is the error that I can't solve for a long time:

ValidationError: Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
- options has an unknown property 'publicPath'. These properties are valid:
object { allowedHosts?, bonjour?, client?, compress?, devMiddleware?, headers?, historyApiFallback?, host?, hot?, http2?, https?, ipc?, liveReload?, magicHtml?, onAfterSetupMiddleware?, onBeforeSetupMiddleware?, onListening?, open?, port?, proxy?, server?, setupExitSignals?, setupMiddlewares?, static?, watchFiles?, webSocketServer? }

Do you have any options for solving this problem? Maybe there is another way to combine them.

**Vue.config.js**

```
var BundleTracker = require('webpack-bundle-tracker')
var WriteFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin')
module.exports = {
  outputDir: (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? 'dist' : 'static'),
  publicPath: '/',
 devServer: {
    publicPath: "http://localhost:8080/",
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
    }
  },
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.optimization.splitChunks({
      cacheGroups: {
        vendors: {
          name: 'chunk-vendors',
          test: /[\\\/]node_modules[\\\\/]/,
          priority: -10,
          chunks: 'initial'
        },
        common: {
          name: 'chunk-common',
          minChunks: 2,
          priority: -20,
          chunks: 'initial',
          reuseExistingChunk: true
        }
      }
    })
  },
  configureWebpack: {
    output: {
      filename: 'js/[name].js',
      chunkFilename: 'js/[name].js'
    },
    plugins: [
      new WriteFilePlugin(),
      (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ?
        new BundleTracker({
          filename: 'webpack-stats-prod.json',
          publicPath: '/'
        }) :
        new BundleTracker({
          filename: 'webpack-stats.json',
          publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/'
        })
      )
    ]
  }
}
```

Tried different versions of vue and django. Changed proxy.

Comment: it's `publicPath: "http://localhost:8080/",` that is causing the issue - remove that line